# How can I repair my shower that is leaking from the back of wall?

Tags: shower, pipe

I had my shower remodel a couple of years back, from plain old shower to now cement tile. Now I noticed that when I go to turn the water on, there is water coming up out from the back of the shower wall. I didn't think much of it, til last night when I came to notice there is water coming from underneath my bedroom floor. My bedroom wall faces my shower wall. Can you help me in telling me what it might be?

Comment: I had a similar problem but it didn't come from the plumbing. It was the joints between the tiles which became permeable so I had to replace them all. It's probably not your case but still remember it can be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Gotta open it up to find out.  You can always open the drywall on the backside to get a look into the mixer valve and pipes in that area.  Drywall is much easier to repair than tile and any fixes can usually be done from there as well.  Also you might want to consider adding an access door so inspections/fixes will be easier in the future.

Comment: +1  I guess this is the answer. Nothing to add here.